# How to make matplotlib Density Map

Tags: matplotlib

Let's say I have two lists, `x` and `y` of same length. This length is not fixed, but always nonzero. They are x and y values of  non-negative points.

I want to create a a color density map much like http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fx_files/31726/1/datadensitymap.jpg .

Here's my attempt borrowing from a few places I've found on the internet:

```
density = stats.gaussian_kde([x,y])
color = density([x,y])
x1 = np.array(x)
y1 = np.array(y)
xmin = x1.min()
xmax = x1.max()
ymin = y1.min()
ymax = y1.max()
xscale = (xmax-xmin)/100
yscale = (ymax-ymin)/100
X, Y = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:xscale, ymin:ymax:yscale]
positions = np.vstack([X.ravel(), Y.ravel()])
Z = np.reshape(density(positions).T, X.shape)
cmap = plt.get_cmap("hot")
plt.imshow(np.rot90(Z), cmap=cmap, extent=[xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
plt.scatter(x, y, c=color, cmap=cmap)
```

When I run this code the plot doesn't render; the title and labels are mashed together.

When I take out the call to imshow, the scatterplot shows perfectly with the density colors on the points showing correctly.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, the plot was rendering, but because `x` had values much larger than `y` the rendered graph had no height. Setting `aspect="auto"` fixed it:

```
plt.imshow(np.rot90(Z), cmap=cmap, extent=[xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax], aspect="auto")
```